# Return value from case statement in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, case, plpgsql

How can I set a value (or just return a value directly) from a user defined function that uses a `case` statement?

```
create function is_bar(email varchar) returns boolean as
$$
declare returnValue boolean;
begin
  select case when exists
  (select * from (users join user_roles on users.userID = user_roles.userID)
  where user_email=email and user_role='bar')
    then (returnValue := TRUE);
    else (returnValue := FALSE);
  end;
  return returnValue;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

gives me:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
LINE 8: then (returnValue := TRUE);
```

Comment: You can't assign a variable like that. You need to use PL/pgSQL's `select into`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much easier to return the result of the `exists` operator itself:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_bar(email VARCHAR) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM   users
                 JOIN   user_roles ON users.userID = user_roles.userID
                 WHERE  user_email = email AND user_role='bar')
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: That would be MUCH easier. I will mark as answered, but just out of interest, why is my current function failing?

Answer (score 5):

The reason of described issue is change of SQL (functional) `CASE` statement and PLpgSQL (procedural) `CASE` statement.

The SQL `CASE` (functional):

```
BEGIN
   RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS(..)
               THEN true /* value */
               ELSE false END; /* ended by END */
END;
```

The PLpgSQL (procedural) `CASE`:

```
BEGIN
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(..)
    THEN
       RETURN true; /* statement */ 
    ELSE
       RETURN false;
  END CASE; /* ended by END CASE */
END;
```

There are some other examples (same result):

```
a := CASE WHEN b < 10 THEN true ELSE false END;
a := b < 10;
CASE WHEN b < 10 THEN
  a := true;
ELSE
  a := false;
END CASE;
```